# Laravel 5.3 Api Routes working on local but not on server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have a Laravel 5.3 project with VUE.js. I'm using vue-router also.

As this app is a Single Page Application, i'm using AJAX from vue-resourse for all the data requests.

In my routes/web.php I have this:

```
Route::any( '/{any?}/{any2?}/{any3?}', 'AdminController@index' );
```

So every route should execute the index method of my AdminController, the routes are in charge of vue-router. This is working perfect.

The problem is in the api routes that manage all the ajax requests. I'm using the routes/api.php for this without any middleware.

In my local environment all of this is working fine but when I uploaded this to a Ubuntu 16 VPS on AWS all the api routes are giving me a 500 Error with this log:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure the answer without more context, but my guess would be that in your Admin Controller there is a redirect happening or something. Or you something like an https force redirect is happening or something. That is what I would suspect since it is happening on prod and not dev.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer!

I don´t know how (probably me drunk) I had the .htaccess in the proyect folder and not in the public folder...